# How to write to and read from a file in Visual C++/CLI?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I am a new learner of the CLI. My teacher posts the following code as an example of hwo to save an object into a file and read an object from the file. I think I understand the code. Now, my teacher also post a question of how to save an array of objects and also read an array of objects (same types).

Q1. How I can know that how many objects in the file?

Q2. What commands should I use to write and read an array of object?

Thanks.

```
Player ^Joe = gcnew Player("Joe", "Human", "Thief", 10, 18, 9, 13, 10, 11);
Console::WriteLine("Original Joe");
Joe->Print();

FileStream ^plStream = File::Create((args->Length==1)?args[0]:"Player.dat");
BinaryFormatter ^f = gcnew BinaryFormatter();
f->Serialize(plStream, Joe);
plStream->Close();

plStream = File::OpenRead((args->Length==1)?args[0]:"Player.dat");
Player ^JoeClone = (Player^)f->Deserialize(plStream);
plStream->Close();

Console::WriteLine("\nCloned Joe");
JoeClone->Print();
```

Answer (score 1):

For Q1, a simple way to know how many Objects are in the file is when writing the file, have the first thing written be the number of Objects in the array.

Having that written down, you can have it loop through in the reading process. I'll let you come up with code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Put you objects into one of the standard containers (for example, a generic list), and serialize / deserialize that list.

The example, in the docs show you how to do this with a Hashtable instead of a List, should not be too hard to adapt this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5sbs8z9.aspx